# How to remove UIWebView from Pod frameworks?

Tags: swift, uiwebview, inmobi, adcolony, vungle-ads

I have implemented Google Ads with some partner networks. but some of them uses `UIWebView` and when i upload build to appStore getting warning like this.

**ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will no longer accept submissions of new apps that use UIWebView as of April 30, 2020 and app updates that use UIWebView as of December 2020. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability.**

**Note:** i have searched `UIWebView` word in my project but wasn't found it.

i use this command in terminal and through this it gives the framework list which uses `UIWebView`.

here is the screenshot.

[image]

Here is my pods

```
pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationAdColony'
pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationInMobi'
pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationVungle'
```

Please guide me to fix this?

Comment: try pod install or update may be it fixes the issue

Comment: @MuhammadAqeel, Already have the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Please check latest Google Ads version after 7.55.0

**Release Notes**
https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rel-notes

> Removed all references to UIWebView. UIWebView is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

No need to remove UIWebView from the Google Ads Pod framework.
I have it in the GoogleMobileAds binary file, but hadn’t any problems.
Try to do the follows:

1. Add new row and set a key and value in your info.plist to use WKWebView instead of UIWebView.

Key: gad_preferred_webview

Value: wkwebview

2. Create and upload archive to the App Store

It works for me